# Do nothing on IF condition if outcome is false in Formula field

Tags: apex, formula-field

I have a Picklist **Status__c**, and **Status_change_date__c**(date field) its value gets updated when the picklist value is changed, this happens through Process Builder.

I need to Calculate No. of days a status has stayed in excluding weekends. So I have created a Formula field 
**Days_InProcess__c** (Number)

```
IF( 
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'InProcess') , 
((5 * (FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE( 1900, 1, 8))/7)) + MIN(5, MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7))) 
- 
(5 * (FLOOR(( status_change_date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8))/7)) + MIN(5, MOD(status_change_date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7)))) 
, 
0)
```

It's updating perfectly. But when I change the Picklist to some other value automatically this field changes to **0** as I have mentioned in the IF condition. Is there any way that the value does not change and stays the same if Picklist value is updated to some other value. Thanks.

Comment: This situation seems like you're confused on the requirements. If the timestamp field tells you its' the date the status was changed, then you should update the value if the status does in fact change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `0` you will need to provide that field which you are updating.

So, your formula would be

```
IF( 
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'InProcess') , 
((5 * (FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE( 1900, 1, 8))/7)) + MIN(5, MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7))) 
- 
(5 * (FLOOR(( status_change_date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8))/7)) + MIN(5, MOD(status_change_date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7)))) 
, 
Days_InProcess__c )
```

### Edit

Good catch by @Adrian, right now you are just checking if the `status` value is `In Process` not changed at all. In case if you do wanna check whether the status was changed or not, use `IsChanged(fieldname)` function.

your formula could look like (if the above assumptions are correct)

```
IF( 
IsChanged(Status__c), 
((5 * (FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE( 1900, 1, 8))/7)) + MIN(5, MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7))) 
- 
(5 * (FLOOR(( status_change_date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8))/7)) + MIN(5, MOD(status_change_date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7)))) 
, 
Days_InProcess__c )
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. "Formula cannot use another formula field that directly or indirectly refers to itself." got this error

Comment: You need to change the field type of `Days_InProcess__c`, from formula to number. You are setting this field using process builder, and formula fields can't be set / updated. They are always read-only.

Comment: Thank you Mahmood, that worked perfectly but with few changes in the logic. In process builder condition is When status is in process, then I added the update record criteria on the number field and removed if condition and just added the floor logic. In that way I don’t have to use else situation. the action will take place only when the status is in process, when status is changed the days field is not changing to 0. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce formulas don't store data; they are calculated fresh each time they're viewed. Your formula field cannot store or retain its own previous value.

Is the goal to store the just total number of days that a record spends in the 'In Process' status? If so, why not add an 'End Date' field that you can populate with Process Builder when the record leaves the 'In Process' status? You can alter your formula to use either the end date or today's date if it is blank, and you'll then be able to retain the count of days after the record leaves that status.

If you need more sophisticated tracking of status value history, you might want to create a `Status History` object with a lookup to the object where the `Status__c` field lives. You could use Process Builder to create a `Status History` object for the previous status each time a change occurs, preserving the date range for that status and allowing you to use formulas on the history object to count days.

Comment: Got it. But I need to calculate the No of days for each status, there are close to 10 statuses. Need to know how many days that field lived in that status.

I need to use this for Reporting, also I need to calculate how many days it took to complete the entire status, for example from status Inprocess - status Approved it took 10 days.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to use the history object approach.